# Where can I sell things for bitcoins?

Tags: bitcoin-economy, ecommerce

I have old items that I want to sell for bitcoins. This includes digital content and physical objects.

What websites can I use to sell them?

Comment: Maybe also try Craigslist. Your ad will be seen by many more people then on bitcoin sites. Of course, most of those will have no idea what bitcoin is. But that way you'll be promoting Bitcoin among the general public. ;-)

Comment: http://sell-deigital.okitoo.net ... bitcoin or paypal . 0% comission !!!

Answer (score 11):

You can find an extensive list on page [Trade at Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Auction_sites).

A short list of some auction sites that use Bitcoins:

- [Bid Bitcoins](http://bidbitcoins.com/#6411e8d2e639)
- [Bidding Pond](https://www.biddingpond.com/)
- [Bitmit](http://www.bitmit.net/)

If you want to sell digital files per download, go here: http://bitcoinservice.co.uk/ .

And as with anything, you can just post on an online classified ad websites, such as [craigslist](http://www.craigslist.com) (thanks Thilo for the suggestion).

Comment: Bidnapper is not a site to sell things for Bitcoin. Its just a Sniping service for eBay and many other auction sites. I can't even find on their site that they accept Bitcoin, just says Paypal and credit card.

Comment: @miernik Edited accordingly

Comment: Interesting that 18 months later none of the three sites you list operates any more.

Answer (score 6):

http://bitcoinservice.co.uk/ allows you to upload a file and receive payment from people downloading it, in case your digital content is of a kind suitable for this format.

Update Apr 24 2012: https://www.coindl.com is looking to become the new bitcoinservice.co.uk.

Answer (score 3):

For digital content, coinDL is worth a shot: https://www.coindl.com (full disclosure: it is developed and operated by myself).

Answer (score 3):

You can also post your goods & services on BitcoinTrading.com: bitcoin buy/sell classifieds.

http://www.bitcointrading.com/

Comment: https://www.qrypto.space/sell is also a great place.

Answer (score 2):

http://CheaperInbitcoins.com You can buy or sell as many items as you want for free, you only pay for upgrades. You can sell items anonymously and as the owner I can vouch for my self and say that we are incorporating our website with an up and coming Web Of Trust ratings system to provide safe, secure and anonymous person to person transactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are selling a digital product you can use http://instabuck.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it for this purpose but I believe [Mokimarket](http://www.mokimarket.com/) allows you to sell items in a penny auction format.

Answer (score 0):

Most popular is 
[BitMit.com](http://www.bitmit.com)

You can also check the complete list at [bitcoin wiki.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Auction_sites)

Comment: "most popular" {{citation needed}}